Prevent recalculations for the PostgreSQL function when using pagination
I have an issue. I have a route named updates that users request with an offset and limit (the limit is 200, and I have more than 200,000 records, so it could be called 1,000 times). The route uses a PostGraphile query with an offset and limit, and the query calls a PostgreSQL function named search_users, which takes 5 seconds to execute.
We have a problem because I think the database function is called again and recalculates for every request to updates (with a different offset). This way, the function calculates over all 200,000 records every time, even though I only need 200 records per request.
I'm trying to figure out what to do. The search_users function includes an ORDER BY clause (I understand this is necessary because SELECT cannot guarantee the same order when using pagination in the PostgreSQL function).
In my opinion, we need to extract all the records initially and use something that remembers the function call between some updates requests (I don't think this exists by default).
I would be happy for technological solutions to solve the problem or any that exist that I do not know.
I tried to raise the limit per request to reduce the load, but I'm not sure if my server can handle 200,000 records without pagination. I also tried to find ways to improve the function itself. I thought about using Materialized Views and indexes to save the result of the function calculation from call to call, but I'm not really sure how to do it.

The question is a bit too generic. Perhaps this article can help you find an efficient pagination method for your use case.

which takes 5 seconds to execute I would spend some time to improve the performance of this function. We measure only in milliseconds, not seconds.

"I'm not sure if my server can handle 200,000 records without pagination"  I don't know either, but what have you got to lose by trying it?  Of the people who load the first page, how many are going to continue on to reading the 2nd through 1000th pages?  Of those who don't, is it because they found what they wanted already on the first page, or because they gave up due to slowness?  These are probably not questions strangers on the internet can answer for you.

You can assign a specific page number to a row during construction of the materialized view using row_number() function and number of rows per page. Something like: (See domo)
-- create materialized view with 'page' number
create materialized view <mat_view>( <list of columns>   
                                   , page  
                                   ) as 
         select *
              , 1+(row_number() over())/2000   -- assign page number with 2000 items per page 
           from (select <list of columns>
                   from <source_table) 
                  order by <column list>
                ); 

NOTE: Demo generates 10010 rows and page size of 20.  
Warning 
Materialized views are static between refreshes. This means stale data as any DML applied to the underlying table(s) will not be reflected between refreshes. Further, refreshing at each cycle will most likely not be performant. You will need to determine the time frame for allowing stale data, and thus the refresh interval.
